# Arrange images and scale to fit a defined area

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm looking for a script that will take a bunch of images (of differing widths and heights) and arrange them into a perfect rectangle as shown below;

[image]

I have been looking at isotope (http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/images.html), but it doesn't resize the images to fit neatly.

Wondering if there is some javascript or php that could do this?

Thanks.

Comment: What's the algorithm you want to use? How should it decide whether to tile or resize a given image?

Answer (score 1):

You can check [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/149445/Rectangle-Tiling-Algorithm) out for some code samples.

And [this](http://www.csc.liv.ac.uk/~epa/surveyhtml.html) link would provide you with some rudimentary knowledge of the various algorithms that are being used to serve this purpose.

[Here](https://github.com/jakesgordon/bin-packing/) is a Bin packing javascript library that you can use and the theory behind it can be found [here](http://codeincomplete.com/posts/2011/5/7/bin_packing/).